# Is there a way to dynamically resize components in a html/cshtml page according to the current window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Right now I have a webpage that contains multiple panels created using a foreach loop that contains textareas/textboxes. When I resize my browser window, it completely screws up the UI as it shifts the position of the textareas and other stuff. Is there a way to allow all the components auto-resize according to the window size so it doesn't mess up the UI?

Here is the code that I use to create the panels:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="max-height:66vh; min-width:100vh">
   <div class="panel-heading" style="max-height:15vh">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.position)
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div style="float:left; margin:6px;">
         <img id="profileImg" height="155" width="155" />
      </div>
      <div style="float:left; margin:6px; margin-right:10px; min-width:50vh">
         @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.description, 7, 200, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
      </div>
      <div style="float:left; margin:6px; min-width:50vh">
         <h5>Comments:</h5>
         @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.comment, new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 70, @rows = 5 })
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use [CSS3 Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: What you're looking for is CSS media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen by looking at the link you guys posted, it seems like media queries changes the UI by taking in the device's dimension almost like an if condition. However, I'm trying to look for something that auto resizes webpage components as the user drags and resizes the browser window simultaneously.

Comment: Look up "Responsive Web Design". This design methodology allows you to create the kind of responsiveness you are looking for. Also, it uses Media Queries.

Comment: @yfan183 you're correct in that media queries are conditionally applied. However when a user resizes their browser window, the browser will automatically reflow the content and reapply the CSS using the new window dimensions. It isn't something you need to do manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

he @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices. In CSS3 it is called media queries. Media queries look at the capability of the device, and can be used to check many things, such as: width and height of the viewport.

You can check out these links -[How to create a mobile version of site](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

[Learning Basics of Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: by looking at the link you posted, it seems like media queries changes the UI by taking in the device's dimension almost like an if condition. However, I'm trying to look for something that auto resizes webpage components as the user drags and resizes the browser window simultaneously.

Comment: I dont think we can do that...depending upon screen dimension, width we need to change our css.